# How can I know which elements are in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a python beginner and would like to learn how to get the names of the elements in a list. For example, if I have

```
input = [1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 'a', 'a']
```

then I'd like to get

```
output = [1, 2.5, 'a']
```

If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: just use output = list(set(input))

Comment: Do you need to keep the order?

Comment: To keep order: `[*dict.fromkeys(input)]`

Comment: You can also use numpy,

    import numpy as np
    
    input = [1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 'a', 'a']
    
    input_unique = np.unique(input)
    print(input_unique)

The result:

    ['1' '2.5' 'a']